# Is this true $X^TY\le ||X||\cdot||Y||$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two real valued vectors with equal dimensions. Is it true to say $X^TY\le ||X||\cdot||Y||$ where  $X^T$ is the transpose of the vector $X$ and $ ||X||$ denotes the 2-norm of the vector $X$ that is : $ ||X||=\sqrt{X^TX}$

Comment: I believe this is called the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality

Comment: Schwarz not Schwartz !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true.

We have $X^TY\le |X^TY| \le ||X||.||Y||$

The first inequality is trivial, the second is Cauchy- Schwarz.